# Grow the VMFS Datastore in to the new space using the vmkfstools fails

Tags: vmware-esxi

I followed [Growing a local datastore from the command line](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?cmd=displayKC&docType=kc&docTypeID=DT_KB_1_1&externalId=1009125) to grow my local datastore from the command line. Everything went fine, except Step 11.

In my case:

```
 vmkfstools --growfs /vmfs/devices/disks/naa.5000c5004dd693ca:3 /vmfs/devices/disks/naa.5000c5004dd693ca:3
```

It says:

```
Error: No such file or directory
```

However the file definitely exists:

```
/dev/disks # ls -Al
-rw-------    1 root     root      1000204886016 Oct  8 18:43 naa.5000c5004dd693ca
-rw-------    1 root     root          939524096 Oct  8 18:43 naa.5000c5004dd693ca:1
-rw-------    1 root     root         4293918720 Oct  8 18:43 naa.5000c5004dd693ca:2
-rw-------    1 root     root       892567249408 Oct  8 18:43 naa.5000c5004dd693ca:3
-rw-------    1 root     root            4177920 Oct  8 18:43 naa.5000c5004dd693ca:4
-rw-------    1 root     root          262127616 Oct  8 18:43 naa.5000c5004dd693ca:5
-rw-------    1 root     root          262127616 Oct  8 18:43 naa.5000c5004dd693ca:6
-rw-------    1 root     root          115326976 Oct  8 18:43 naa.5000c5004dd693ca:7
-rw-------    1 root     root          299876352 Oct  8 18:43 naa.5000c5004dd693ca:8
```

Why do I get the  No such file or directory or directory error?

Comment: The example in the article has double quotes around the filenames.  Did you try your command with double quotes?

Comment: Why are you doing this from the command line?

Comment: I also tried with double quotes, same error

Comment: @Chopper3 Is there another way doing it?

Comment: @markus So you've extended the underlying logical drive right? why wouldn't you just use the VSClient/GUI to extend the DS?

Comment: I cant do it with the client the button to expand is greyed out

Comment: I found another thread discussing the same issue: http://communities.vmware.com/message/2008814