# ESXi - expanding vmdk file fails with insufficient space on file system

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-vmdk

I receive the following error

`Failed to extend disk : There is not enough space on the file system for the selected operation (13).`

When I run this command: `vmkfstools -X 240G srvr.vmdk`
The disk is thick provisioned, lazy zeroed.
The host is ESXi 5.1.
The guest is Windows Server 2012.
The datastore is mapped to a compellent storage device. The volume on the compellent was expanded from 80GB to 250GB. It maps correctly, and I can power on the guest OS.

The original request was for a simple test server, which, after deployment, changed, and required the system to have additional space. I retrieved a replay from the compellent and expanded the volume. Then mapped it back to the ESXi host. The volume on the compellent shows the full 250GB. Now I need to expand the datastore.

Am I using the wrong command for this? I am unable to expand the vmdk from the GUI either.

EDIT:

> Filesystem        Bytes         Used    Available Use% Mounted on
>   VMFS-5     294473695232   1158676480 293315018752   0% /vmfs/volumes/datastore1
>   VMFS-5     139318001664   2864709632 136453292032   2% /vmfs/volumes/somevm
>   VMFS-5     160792838144 125716922368  35075915776  78% /vmfs/volumes/anothervm
>   VMFS-5     536602476544 494941503488  41660973056  92% /vmfs/volumes/andanother
>   VMFS-5      64156073984  63406342144    749731840  99% /vmfs/volumes/andanother
>   VMFS-5      85630910464  81241571328   4389339136  95% /vmfs/volumes/THE_ONE_IN_QUESTION
>   vfat         4293591040     24051712   4269539328   1% /vmfs/volumes/50ca717d-17c1122c-dbec-2c768a4e2660
>   vfat          261853184    153255936    108597248  59% /vmfs/volumes/2bb93c74-2cc389b3-62c1-8dec8ed7d2d2
>   vfat          261853184         8192    261844992   0% /vmfs/volumes/2c3de672-0bfb1f9c-3398-32baad5c2871
>   vfat          299712512    211755008     87957504  71% /vmfs/volumes/50ca7177-21183a3e-94c4-2c768a4e2660

Comment: Wait, you say ESXi, but them mention VHD. Did you mean VMDK by any chance?

Comment: Have you grown the datastore before trying to extend the vmdk?

Comment: @MDMarra my mistake. Yes I meant VMDK. Not quite up on all the terminology.

Comment: @Marki I guess not. I thought that is what the failed command was supposed to do.

Comment: The LUN from the storage array represents a VMFS datastore. The VMDKs represent the virtual disks of the VMs. After expanding a LUN on the array, you first need to grow the datastore before being able to extend the VMDK. Maybe I don't understand your setup. Can you please show the output of `df` on the ESXi host?

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to expand the VMDK but you haven't extended the datastore (as others have mentioned).

Comment: @joeqwerty I'm beginning to get that feeling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just posting as an answer, so you can accept ;-)

The LUN from the storage array represents a VMFS datastore. The VMDKs represent the virtual disks of the VMs. After expanding a LUN on the array, you first need to grow the datastore before being able to extend the VMDK.

Clearly (from the output of `df`): 85630910464 = 80G. So the VMFS still had the old size.

Answer (score 1):

I did, as indicated in the comments, have to grow the datastore. The datastore would not initially allow me to increase it through the GUI, since I did not re-signature when I mapped it over.
 [This](https://communities.vmware.com/message/2008814) and [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/436096/grow-the-vmfs-datastore-in-to-the-new-space-using-the-vmkfstools-fails) helped me find the solution.